# Setting column widths for <table> in Django

Tags: html, css, django, templates, html-table

I have a django app where I want to display a model's objects. As a result, I have used an inclusion tag in my approach that returns a table of data and is used to display the results in my template. Thus, in the following custom inclusion tag,

```
*dir_extras.py*
@register.inclusion_tag('app_name/model_data.html')
def field_data(field):
    data_list = Attributes.objects.values_list(field, flat=True)    
    return {'data_list':data_list}
```

i am returning a list of field objects for the model class Attributes. The template that renders the tag is the following:

```
*model_data.html*
{% load dir_extras %}
<table> 
{% for data in data_list %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{data}} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

And the template where I run my field_data tag and display all Attributes data is the following:

```
*list.html*
<table>
<tr>
    {% for field in fields %}
        <th>{{ field.verbose_name }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        {% for f_name in field_names %}
                <td> {% field_data f_name %} </td>
        {% endfor %}    
    </tr>   
 </table>
```

Although all of the table columns are aligned, still the format of the rows is inconsistent. So, the elements of the rows are not aligned with each other but instead the first element is spanning so much that is aligned with the elements of other 5 rows.

[list.html template image](http://imageshack.us/a/img802/7295/pbtu.png)

Is the formatting changed due to the inclusion tag or is it another issue and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your HTML table formatting with CSS. CSS has options to set which of the columns are auto-expanding. You can define column widths with percents or pixels.

Give CSS classes to your `<th>` and `<td>`:

```
<table class="my-listing">
<tr>
    {% for field in fields %}
        <th class="column-{{ field.verbose_name|slugify }}">{{ field.verbose_name }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        {% for f_name in field_names %}
                <td class="column-{{ f_name|slugify }}"> {% field_data f_name %} </td>
        {% endfor %}    
    </tr>   
 </table>
```

Use CSS to control the column expansion:

```
 /* Default width of the column */
 .my-listing td,
 .my-listing th {
      width: 10%;
 }

 /* Width of one specific column */
 .column-id {
       width: 10%;
 }
```

[Django documentation how to have static assets like CSS with your app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

[Styling tables with CSS](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Styling_tables).

Use your web browser debugging tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to modify CSS styles in-fly to experiement and find good values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the really detailed answer you provided! In the beginning I thought it was an issue with django but in the end CSS was responsible for this confusion!